# Position of Android controls ("home", "back", etc.)

Tags: android, android-layout

For more pleasant UI, I'm trying to horizontally align few UI components of my activity with those controls of Android OS, which are always visible at the bottom of the screen: such as "back", "home", etc.

I thought, that Android OS controls are always distributed evenly across the horizontal axis. However, for some devices this is not true. E.g. on my Android Galaxy phone these controls are offset by few pixels, probably because of curved screen edges (just a guess).

I was searching for some generic Android API, which would give me access to these controls, but with no luck.

So my question would be: is there a **robust** way to horizontally align widgets of my Activity with Android OS controls visible at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

> which are always visible at the bottom of the screen: such as "back", "home", etc.

[They are not always visible on the bottom of the screen](https://www.androidpolice.com/how-to-use-gesture-navigation-on-android/). That link refers to the four-year-old official Android support for gesture navigation; various manufacturers offered gesture navigation prior to that.

> I thought, that Android OS controls are always distributed evenly across the horizontal axis. However, for some devices this is not true.

Device manufacturers can do whatever they want.

> is there a robust way to horizontally align widgets of my Activity with Android OS controls visible at the bottom of the screen?

No.